# How do you translate the idiom "to pop" as in "a thought popped into my head"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

Is the verb *sauter* (to jump) the correct one?

Comment: About the "as in", for such kind of things, I'd translate the whole sentence and not expect the verb used to be usable in other contexts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend *venir à l'esprit*:

> Une pensée me vient à l'esprit
>   Une pensée m'est venue à l'esprit
>   Une pensée me vint à l'esprit

Or maybe *traverser l'esprit* (although the thought usually stays in your mind, so it's a bit odd, but used nevertheless):

> Une pensée me traverse l'esprit
>   Une pensée m'a traversé l'esprit
>   Une pensée me traversa l'esprit

By the way, I would tend to say that the prsent is more used in French than the past, emphasizing the fact that the thought is now in your head.

But really, as the thought wasn't in your mind (*esprit*) before, and it's there now, other verbs indicating that move could do. As Cédric [says](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1306), *surgir dans l'esprit*, for example; for more exotic verbs, try:

> Une pensée se forme dans mon esprit
>   Une pensée apparaît dans mon esprit
>   Une pensée germe dans mon esprit

Comment: [Gilles](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1311) is right though, _il me vient une idée_ is more common than _une idée me vient (à l'esprit)_

Answer (score 10):

In your example, I would translate *pop* into "**surgir**".

> Une pensée surgit dans mon esprit

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Isn't the past tense une pensee a surgi, then?

Comment: @CarpeDiem correct, but the present tends to be used more in French in this case, I believe.

Comment: I took _surgit_ as a simple past (which has the same forms as the present in the singular).

Comment: I was in doubt about the correct form of surgir.... I'm happy to see I'm not alone ;)

Comment: +1 pour la traduction de l'activité de la forme : une pensée peut certes éclore, mais à ce moment-là elle ne *pop* pas, ou bien vous avez de droles de fleurs.

Answer (score 7):

De façon assez idiomatique :

> Je viens d'avoir une idée.

Sinon, une pensée peut aussi *éclore* (comme les fleurs).

Answer (score 6):

La première idée qui m'est passée par la tête est « il me vient quelque chose à l'esprit », ou un peu plus familièrement « il me vient un truc à l'esprit » ou en plus court « il me vient un truc », ou encore « quelque chose me passe par la tête ».

À l'oral, le but d'une telle expression plus longue que « I just thought of something » (qu'on peut rendre par « je viens de penser à quelque chose » ou plus simplement « j'y pense : ... ») est en partie de laisser le temps à la pensée de se former. On peut lui rajouter des mots inutiles, par exemple : « Au fait, dis-donc, il me vient quelque chose à l'esprit, là, tout d'un coup. Est-ce que des fois ça serait possible que ... »

Dans une narration, je rejoins assez les [propositions de Joubarc](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/how-do-you-translate-the-idiom-to-pop-as-in-a-thought-popped-into-my-head/1308#1308), quoique j'aurais tendance à conserver la tournure impersonnelle du verbe *venir* : « une pensée me traversa l'esprit », « il me vint soudainement une idée à l'esprit ». Un peu moins formellement, on peut écrire « une pensée me traversa la tête » voire « il m'est tout à coup venu une idée en tête ».

Comment: Je pense à un truc, ta réponse commence de manière fort appropriée.